# Strange pass by reference issue in a simple program

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am implementing Sudoku solver and using 2D vector and passing it around using reference but still, when at the end of the main I try to print the 2D vector it prints the initial 2D vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void display(vector<vector<int>>& _board) {
    for (auto row: _board) {
        for (auto col: row) {
            cout << col << "  ";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
}


bool isBoardSolved(vector<vector<int>>& _board) {
    for (auto row: _board) {
        for (auto col: row) { //style[1] of 2D vector traversal
            if (col == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

map<int, int> findOptions(vector<vector<int>>& _board, int _row, int _col) {
    map<int, int> options;
    int x, y;
    for (int digit = 1; digit < 10; ++digit) {
        options[digit] = 0; //state 0 means available as options
    }
    //col in a row
    for (y = 0; y < 9; ++y) {
        if (_board[_row][y] != 0) {
            options[_board[_row][y]] = 1;
        }
    }
    //row in a col
    for (x = 0; x < 9; ++x) {
        if (_board[x][_col] != 0) {
            options[_board[x][_col]] = 1;
        }
    }
    //in a rectangular 3*3 matrix
    if (_row <= 2)
        x = 0;
    else if (_row > 2 && _row <= 5)
        x = 3;
    else
        x = 6;
    if (_col <= 2)
        y = 0;
    else if (_col > 2 && _col <= 5)
        y = 3;
    else
        y = 6;



    for (int i = x; i < x + 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = y; j < y + 3; ++j) {
            if (_board[i][j] != 0) {
                options[_board[i][j]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return options;

}

void solveBoard(vector<vector<int>>& _board) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    if (isBoardSolved(_board)) {
//        cout << "Solved Sudoku Board" << endl;
//        display(_board); //gives correct answer when I print it here
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++x) { //not using the style[1] because I need explicit index of empty slot
            flag = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y) {
                if (_board[x][y] == 0) {
                    row = x;
                    col = y;
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
                break;
        }
    }

    auto options = findOptions(_board, row, col);
    for (auto digit: options) {
        if (digit.second != 1) {
            _board[row][col] = digit.first;
            solveBoard(_board);
        }
    }
    _board[row][col] = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<vector<int>> board(9, vector<int>(9, 0));

    board[0][3] = 3;
    board[0][6] = 2;
    board[2][1] = 7;
    board[2][2] = 8;
    board[2][3] = 0;
    board[2][4] = 6;
    board[2][6] = 3;
    board[2][7] = 4;
    board[3][1] = 4;
    board[3][2] = 2;
    board[3][3] = 5;
    board[3][4] = 1;
    board[4][0] = 1;
    board[4][1] = 0;
    board[4][2] = 6;
    board[4][6] = 4;
    board[4][7] = 0;
    board[4][8] = 9;
    board[5][4] = 8;
    board[5][5] = 6;
    board[5][6] = 1;
    board[5][7] = 5;
    board[6][1] = 3;
    board[6][2] = 5;
    board[6][4] = 9;
    board[6][6] = 7;
    board[6][7] = 6;
    board[7][3] = 7;
    board[8][2] = 9;
    board[8][5] = 5;

    cout << "Given Sudoku Board" << endl;
    display(board);
    solveBoard(board);
    cout << "Solved Sudoku Board" << endl;
    display(board); //gives unchanged answer when i print it here
}
```

What is wrong I am doing and how to correct it.

When I try this :

```
void change(vector<vector<int>>& _b){
    _b[0][1] = 99;
}
int main(){

    vector<vector<int>> b(1, vector<int>(9, 1));
    cout<<b[0][1]<<endl;
    change(b);
    cout<<b[0][1];
    return 0;    
}
```

This displays the changed value for 2D vecor b.

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. So, when you used your debugger to execute your program, one line at a time, and examining the values of all variables, what observations have you made? (P.S. your solve algorithm looks fundamentally broken to me).

Comment: I think the problem is because of the line _board[row][col] = 0; at the end of solveBoard function. You solve the board and revert the changes at the end.

Comment: @jyotesh: No, it's not. It's for backtrack.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Not helping.

Comment: On a contrary: this is the best help anyone can give you. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Once you learn how to do that, you will no longer have any reason to wait for answers from strangers on stackoverflow.com. You can find and fix bugs in your own code! Isn't that a better position to be in, to figure out how to make your own code work, rather than relying on others?

Comment: All these people here saying "use a debugger" seem to be confusing debugging with the debugger. There is no need to use a debugger to debug a program - I almost never do so.

Comment: @RoshanMehta When you finish solving the board, you go to the if(isBoardSolved) part. You return from there, which returns the control to the line after solveBoard function call in the previous stack frame. After you exit out of that for loop, you revert the change by setting _board[row][col] to 0. That's why when you print the board in if condition, it prints the correct output and when you print in main it is back to original. You can easily verify this using a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not exiting the recursion call stack correctly in solveBoard(). Note the new bool function signature for solveBoard() being returned to signal up the invocation chain to exit early.  Also note the three different return points now depending on where you are.

```
bool solveBoard(vector<vector<int>>& _board) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    bool flag;
    if (isBoardSolved(_board)) {
//      cout << "Solved Sudoku Board" << endl;
//      display(_board); //gives correct answer when I print it here
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++x) { //not using the style[1] because I need explicit index of empty slot
            flag = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y) {
                if (_board[x][y] == 0) {
                    row = x;
                    col = y;
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
                break;
        }
    }

    auto options = findOptions(_board, row, col);
    for (auto digit : options) {
        if (digit.second != 1) {
            _board[row][col] = digit.first;
            if (solveBoard(_board))
                return true;
        }
    }
    _board[row][col] = 0;
    return false;
}
```